# cancellation visa for kuwait

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, cancellations, visa-cancellation

I have a valid visa from Kuwait but the problem is that [Kuwait is banned for deployment as per our President's declaration](http://www.pna.gov.ph/articles/1024931).

Are we allowed to go personally to Kuwait Embassy here in the Philippines to ask for assistance regarding the process of cancellation of visa.

Comment: How does a visa cancellation help you with anything? can’t you just leave it unused?

Comment: @JanDoggen there was an incident where a filipina maid was found dead in a freezer in the home of her sponsors; which prompted this action.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That news article says *is set to ban the deployment*. Not that I don't believe you, but a reference to the decree being *in effect* would be better. I have replaced your link with an authoratative one from pna.gov

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a valid visa, it remains valid. The restriction is for new visas only. Existing visas are not automatically invalidated.

Further, you cannot request the embassy to cancel your visa. It can only be canceled by the sponsor (at least they have to start the process, and eventually it is marked as revoked by the Ministry of Interior of Kuwait).

If you have a permanent resident (18) or other such visa type of Kuwait, after 6 months of absence the visa is automatically cancelled (it states so on the visa page that is affixed to your passport).

If you have a paper visa (a new visa), then it will be valid for 3 months from the date of issuance. After that date (which is written on the visa paper near the bottom), the visa is not longer valid.